# Changing parents of a 3D model while keeping the same position

Tags: three.js, 3d, positioning

I'm using three.js library to work with 3d models (mostly .glb but it shouldn't matter)

The idea is to import a 3d model that contains groups and meshes. I want to be able to move meshes between already existing groups within a model without changing the visual representation of the model.
Piece of my code is below. movedInternal is

```js
movedMesh.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true; // not sure if it's needed
let meshPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
movedMesh.getWorldPosition(meshPosition);

oldParent.remove(movedMesh);
newParent.add(movedMesh);

movedMesh.worldToLocal(meshPosition);
movedMesh.position.set(meshPosition.x, meshPosition.y, meshPosition.z);
```

And this is not working. Mesh changes its global position because new parent’s position is not the same as previous parent position, but I expect it to stay where it was but change its local position considering new parent’s position.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to update the `movedMesh`'s world matrix *after* you change its parents. When you `.remove()` then `.add()`, it doesn't know that its parents have been updated (Three.js usually does it when you're rendering, but this is happening before the next frame render).

```js
let meshPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
movedMesh.getWorldPosition(meshPosition);

oldParent.remove(movedMesh);
newParent.add(movedMesh);

// Here it needs to re-learn its new coordinates
movedMesh.updateMatrixWorld(true);

movedMesh.worldToLocal(meshPosition);
movedMesh.position.set(meshPosition.x, meshPosition.y, meshPosition.z);
```

Comment: My first answer was wrong, I just updated it with what I think the issue is.

Comment: cool! thank you so much :)
it almost work. I guess I also need to reset its orientation

Is there any trick for that?

Comment: That's a different problem altogether. Give it a shot with [`.getWorldDirection()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.getWorldDirection) and [`.lookAt()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt) and see how far you get. If you get stuck, feel free to ask in another question!

Comment: Sorry, I meant orientation as in ```mesh.rotation```

Like, is it possible to get it using [.getWorldQuaternion](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.getWorldQuaternion) and then translate it from world to new local (maybe by using [.applyQuaternion](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.applyQuaternion))?

Comment: @annwhoorma Try it out and see! I'm pretty certain it is possible.

Comment: It didn't work, I even tried to transalte to Euler. Would you have any other ideas in mind?

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for this solution since a week and haven't been able to tackle the exact problem. Though my question is diferent but has same scenario, I would like to give a solution for those, looking for it.

I have a 3D object with different child meshes, and i want to replace one of my child mesh with another 3D model.
Below code snippet:
`replacementMesh` is a new 3D object, `meshToReplace` is the child mesh that needs to be replaced.

```js
// Copy the transformation matrix from obj1 to obj2
replacementMesh.matrix.copy(meshToReplace.matrix);

// Update obj2's position, rotation, and scale to match the transformation matrix
replacementMesh.position.setFromMatrixPosition(replacementMesh.matrix);    
replacementMesh.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(replacementMesh.matrix);    
replacementMesh.scale.setFromMatrixScale(replacementMesh.matrix);

 meshToReplace.parent.add(replacementMesh);
 meshToReplace.parent.remove(meshToReplace);
```